# Firebase Google Keys and OAuthClient messed up

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have multiple machines to work with. I have an Android backend on Firebase. I tried to add SHA1 for the same and got confused between keys.
I initially got

```
"failed Sign in Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 12501, resolution=null}"
```

as my app used GoogleSignin. I ended up deleting all my keys and credentials. From there, I am trying to create all my credentials for Firebase project.

I now have following on my Google Developers console:
**API KEYS**

1. ServerKey(auto created by Google Service)
2. AndroidKey (auto created by Google Service)

**OAuth 2.0 client IDs**

3. Android Client for com.mypackage (auto created by google service)
4. Web Client 1 (which I created in some process and added my firebase project url as origin)
5. Android Client 1 (my old SHA1 for a different OS/machine)

**Note**: My Firebase project Console also shows a **Web API Key** in Project Settings, which I am not able to find anywhere in my Android project.

In my *`google-services.json`, what I downloaded from Firebase

- **2, 3, 4 & 5** is found in my google-services.json

Now I am stuck on my phone signin screen. Can anyone explain to me where can I start from? I am even ready to remove all keys once again and start.

Comment: @AL have you find the solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Use the web client 1 key in your android project and not the android key.

Also include the google-services.json file your app folder.